# Is there a more efficient method for omitting for loop instances

Tags: c#, performance

If I have a standard for loop is there a more efficient way to omit certain occurances?

For example:

A:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (i != n / 2 && i != n / 3 && i != n / 4)
            {
                val += DoWork(i);
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
```

B:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < n / 4; i++)
        {
            val += DoWork(i); ;
        }
        for (int i = n / 4 + 1; i < n / 3; i++)
        {
            val += DoWork(i);
        }
        for (int i = n / 3 + 1; i < n / 2; i++)
        {
            val += DoWork(i);
        }
        for (int i = n / 2 + 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            val += DoWork(i);
        }
```

C:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (i == n / 2 || i == n / 3 || i == n / 4)
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                val += DoWork(i);
            }
        }
```

For `n = int.MaxValue` the results were as follows:
A Results: 57498 milliseconds.
B Results: 42204 milliseconds.
C Results: 57643 milliseconds.

EDIT BASED ON @Churk 's answer.
I added another test case method D as follows:

D:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i =  (i != n / 2 -1 && i != n / 3 -1  && i != n / 4-1) ? i+1: i+2)
        {
            val += DoWork(i);
        }
```

and got the following results:

A Results: 56355 milliseconds.
B Results: 40612 milliseconds.
C Results: 56214 milliseconds.
D Results: 51810 milliseconds.

Edit2: After pre-calculating values for n/2 n/3 and n/4 outside the loop got:

A Results: 50873 milliseconds.
B Results: 39514 milliseconds.
C Results: 51167 milliseconds.
D Results: 42808 milliseconds.

The D loop seems to be close again to the "unrolling" of B, with A and C still taking significantly more time.

Which are about what I expected, as far as comparisons between each of the methods.

My question is, is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: is this *the* performance bottleneck for your application? It sounds unlikely.

Comment: You don't need `else{continue;}`.  And in `C:` example, change your `if` statement to `if(!(..)){ val += DoWork(i); }` and omit the `else` altogether.

Comment: If you did DoWork(0);DoWork(1);DoWork(2)...DoWork(n) it will probably be even faster.

Comment: Nevermind about my answer, just realized that it will stop the for loop when it hits one of those condition and not continue.

Comment: True. And if it's not hard-coded, It would be worth to pre-calculate those expressions like: n/2, n/3 and assign them variables instead of calculating them every time in the loop.

Comment: @NominSin Our question is... Why do you need to optimize this? Is it worth discussing here?

Comment: @BrokenGlass Did I mention an application at all? This is just an exercise in performance..

Comment: performance always is relative to what you *need*, for most applications clarity and maintainability is much more important in almost all cases. I'd consider this premature optimization.

Comment: **Option A without the else**  is the best performing and readable soution.

Comment: @Shiplu, option A does make more sense from a readability standpoint, but it is significantly slower than option B

Comment: @NominSim oops. I didn't check the algorithm first time. You are right!

Comment: Did you try precalculating n/2, n/3 and n/4 outside the for loop and then compare with the variables? I'm not sure if the JIT compiler is smart enough to do this optimization for you or if it calculates all these values in each iteration.

Comment: @aKzenT Just updated an edit with those value, it improved the performance of them a bit, but A and C are still fairly far off of B. D seems like the best bet overall.

Comment: For comparison it might also be interesting to make a simple loop without skipping any values to see what the theoretical minimum would be.

Comment: @aKzenT The B loop for all intents and purposes is as close to a "simple" loop as you can get, other than the reassignment of i every time, we shouldn't expect any change. (millisecond differences if we removed the int = i before each loop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends a bit on the context. One possiblitiy in many scenarios is to cheat. So instead of omitting the numbers, just include them and later reverse the result from the numbers you didn't want:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    { 
        val += DoWork(i); 
    } 
    val -= DoWork(i/2);
    val -= DoWork(i/3);
    val -= DoWork(i/4);
```

The time you save from comparisons might outweigh the results from calculating some numbers twice, depending on how expensive the DoWork operation is.

Comment: +1 for the thought, even though I have a feeling this doesn't optimize performance in most situations.

Comment: clean implementation only if there is small number of exception cases. And what happen if DoWork depends on certain condition such as a running total at a certain point in time? I am not sure if there is a more graceful way of doing it beside what the op had posted.

Comment: Since the question doesn't provide enough context it's a theoretical exercise. The code doesn't mention any side effects from DoWork. But of course if there are any this might not work. In cases where the performance of the loop is really a consideration it should optimize the performance. If DoWork does a lot of work, then you would try to optimize DoWork instead of the loop. So I assume that n is quite large.

Comment: It really depends how much time DoWork() takes. It will work properly only if DoWork() isn't an expensive operation in relative to the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Embed your secondary condition into you for loop

Untested:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n || (i != n / 2 && i != n / 3 && i != n / 4); i++)
  val += DoWork(i);
}
```

I think this will work as long as one of those condition is true it will keep going

Comment: Its a bit hacky and not that verbose.

Comment: I am second guessing my self, and setting up test cases right now for it. But I think i<n will negate what ever is inside the second condition. Because i<n is a super set of the secondary conditions.

Comment: Yeah I believe so Churk, I experimented with this too, but couldn't get it to work correctly, if you make it `i < n && (i != n / 2 && i != n / 3 && i != n / 4)` that seems more likely to me, but it enters infinite loop after i >= n

Comment: I don't think that's going to work,  because the condition will be checked after every iteration of the loop, and furthermore it will give you incorrect results because you include the occurrences that you should've excluded (**i<n ||**)

Comment: @surfen His isn't exactly right but it led me to the loop in the edit of my question, it actually is noticeably faster than each of the others (other than B which probably will end up being the fastest)

Answer (score 1):

First, just pause it a few times during that 40-60 seconds, so you get a fair idea what fraction of time is in `DoWork`. If you could even make your looping take *no time at all*, you'd still have to spend that part.

Now look at your comparisons.
Each one is asking a question.
If the answer to a question is almost always True or almost always False, it is an opportunity to get speedup.
(All the log(n) and n*log(n) algorithms work by making their decision points more like fair coins.)

So you can see why your B is faster. It is asking fewer questions per loop, on average.
You can make it even faster, by unrolling the loops (asking the questions even less often).

(I know, I know, compilers can unroll loops. Well, *maybe*. Do it yourself and you won't have to bet on it.)

Comment: DoWork is actually a superfluous method, I just wanted to see the times of the various incarnations of the for loops to see if anyone had a more efficient(or readable) way of doing it.

Comment: @NominSim: It's only worth worrying about if 1) this whole thing takes a significant fraction of overall time, and 2) `DoWork` does almost nothing. I only mention that because sometimes people are "penny-wise and pound-foolish".

Comment: Well the improvement from A and C to B or even D seems fairly significant to me (130 percent faster)

Comment: @NominSim: You know what I mean. If this is in a larger app, the fraction of time it spends in this code might be small, *or* `DoWork` might be more like `DoesMoreWorkThanIThoughtItWould`.

Comment: Yes that's true, but if over the course of my life I look at the slight increases in performance by utilizing optimum for loops for each loop it will make me sleep better at night.

Comment: @NominSim: If you can sleep better with a 2.3x speedup I envy you. I've put an example [here, with source code and explanatory slides, of a 730x speedup.](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Profiling.html) My point is, sometimes our expectations are lower than they could be.

Comment: I am just looking for good programming practice, not optimizing specific code. I find that it is often the case that when writing a for loop you want to discount a certain iteration of the loop, just wanted to know what the most efficient way of doing that is. I most certainly can sleep better with more efficient programming practices  . :)

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate the values outside of the loop and then just skip them:

```
  int skip1 = n/2;
  int skip2 = n/3;
  int skip3 = n/4;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
      if (i != skip1 && i != skip2 && i != skip3)
      {
         val += DoWork(i);
      }
  }
```

Not sure if this will save enough milliseconds to be worthwhile, though.

Update: I've just noticed that @surfen suggested this in the comments.

Answer (score -1):

If `DoWork()` isn't the bottleneck, it is a small enough method to embed into the loop, so you won't need the call which costs time by itself. If `DoWork()` does most of the work though, you're the one wasting time :)

Answer (score -1):

You can count operations...

Option A:
`n` checks on `i` in the for loop  and then 3 checks on each i that isn't that value... so there's 4n operations just for the checks.

option B:
You're just looping through intervals, so you're doing `n-3` operations.

option C:
Same as option A, `4n` operations.

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't bother complicating code with such modifications (as many have already commented on your question)

Instead, you might want to run your DoWork simultanuously in multiple threads using [Pararell.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460713.aspx). This would have a much larger impact on performance, if your DoWork() does anything.

Comment: Sometimes a "DoWork" function can't be done in parallel, I was just curious to see if there was a better optimization for that type of situation.

Comment: Then I guess the answer is **NO** (B is the fastest). I'd still go for A because of readability.

Comment: for B you could gain a few more ms if you defined i variable before the loops - you wouldn't have to calculate it before every loop, just continue where you finished.